# Best way to polyfill js app in 2020 with webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs, polyfills

I feel like I do something wrong, overkilling or missing something.  Help me please with my setup

*.babelrc*

```
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "debug": true,
        "useBuiltIns": "usage",
        "corejs": 3
      }
    ],
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ],
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"]
}
```

*webpack.config.js*

```
...
  use: {
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    options: {
      presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'],
      plugins: ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties']
    }
  },
...
```

*package.json*

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.9.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/runtime-corejs3": "^7.9.2",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "core-js": "^3.6.4",
...
```

And finaly my *server.js*

```
...
import 'core-js/stable';
import 'regenerator-runtime/runtime';
...
```